# Finding the any number of characters between brackets using regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

I've been struggling with some regex parsing to get a particular substring out of a string. I want to get the `{0}` out of a string. The caveat is that the substring can have any number of 0'
s within the `{}` and there can be many instances of `{0}` in the String. A few example inputs are:

1. `{0}` should print `{0}`
2. `F-{000}` print `{000}`
3. `F-{00000000}-{0000}` print `{00000000}` & `{0000}`

Here is the code I have:

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String displayFormat = "A-{0000}";
        printValue("^\\{[0]+}$", displayFormat); // this searches for a string beginning with {, ends with }, and has 1 or more instances of 0 in it
        printValue("\\{[0]+\\}", displayFormat); // same as above but without the strict requirement of beginning and ending with {}, rather looks for the literal {}
    }

    public static void printValue(String regex, String displayFormat) {
        final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(displayFormat);
        String zeroSection = null;
        while(matcher.find()) {
            if(matcher.groupCount() > 0) {
                System.out.println("Group: " + matcher.group(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Using `\\{0+\\}` will match `{`, then 1+ times a zero and `}` Is that not the desired result? https://regex101.com/r/ospzoe/1

Comment: Ah yeah, that works. I think I found out the solution, it may have just been with the printing I was doing. I'll post a follow-up answer. Thanks!

Comment: [`groupCount()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount--) *"returns the number of capturing groups in this matcher's pattern"*. Since there are no capturing groups in either regex, it returns 0, so code doesn't print anything.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to find the correct regex. The regex that was posted in the answer above seems to work, but I guess the issue was more around how I was printing the string. I should have been printing `group(0)` instead of `group(1)`. Silly mistake.

Comment: Wrong, because if that had been the *only* error, code would have failed with `IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1`